# PHP Time function issue

Tags: php, time

I need to add X days to current time

```
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i",time());
    echo "<br>";
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i",time()+5*24*60*60);
```

return correct results

```
    18.10.2013 14:22
    23.10.2013 14:22
```

but if i change 5 to 10 then

```
    18.10.2013 14:22
    28.10.2013 13:22
```

13:22 instead of 14:22 in result. 1 hour is missed.

What can be with it?

Comment: Daylight Savings Time? You might have hit a boundary there.

Comment: 27th October is time-shift to winter time.

Comment: What happens if you'd use the following code?  `$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");`

Comment: Try http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php instead.

Comment: @FDL That's incorrect. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @str learn something new everyday - have been doing that for years "just incase" thanks

Comment: Never do date math on your own. There's too many exceptions to account for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daylight savings ends on the 27th of October (so we fall back an hour) which explains the issue you are seeing. Try it with another month and you will get the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**:

examples:

```
echo date("d.m.Y H:i",strtotime("+10 days")) ;
echo date("d.m.Y H:i",strtotime("+6 hours 30 seconds"))
```

strtotime function ignores the transition to winter time.

[**EXAMPLE IN USE**](http://codepad.org/eCe878Jb)

Answer (score 0):

To add day to a date you can use DateTime (maybe will be easier)

[php.net DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php)